# Unable to transfer File History data from older laptop to newer laptop

Tags: windows-10, backup, data-transfer, file-history

I got a new laptop, and I'm trying to transfer some data from my older laptop. I've been using File History to store backups on an external hard drive. My new laptop has an 1TB SSD, and I've been trying to restore the backed up files onto it.

Originally, when I transferred between the two drives, I copied and pasted the files. However, they had a timestamp added to their file names. So I reformatted the SSD to make room for the actual backup. I did the following:

1. Connected the hard drive containing the backup
2. `Control Panel\System and Security` → *File History*
3. *Restore your files with File History* → *Configure File History settings*
4. Checked *I want to use a previous backup on this File History drive*
5. Selected the existing backup → *Turn on* → I receive error:

   > Could not reassociate with File History data - The system cannot find the path specified

   - I've been looking around for a solution, but can't find one, and when I try to start File History from Settings, I receive error `0x8007000E`

How do I resolve this?

Comment: In `Control Panel\System and Security\File History`, is the path to the File History directory correct?

Comment: @JW0914 For "Copy files from", it says "Libraries, Desktop, Contacts, and Favorites". For "Copy files to", it says the drive that contains my backup. Is that what you mean?

Comment: No, if you open that path in Windows Explorer, is the File History drive path in the box correct? It should be the path to the parent directory above your username _(e.g. if path is `Z:\Backup\File History\<username>`, then the correct path would be `Z:\Backup\File History`)_. If that's correct. in Explorer open `Z:\Backup\File History\<name>\<username>` - does the correct hostname folder exist?

Comment: @JW0914 It looks right. Is the username in the backup folder suppose to match the new laptop's username?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Turns out the paths in the config files didn't match up with what File History was looking for. For instance, File History was looking for the E: drive when the config was storing the F: drive. So I changed them, and it worked flawlessly.